# Dust.js - Syntax : Define a context for a loop

Tags: loops, dust.js

I'm learning the syntax of DustJS with the [Getting Start](http://www.dustjs.com/guides/getting-started/#looping) of the documentation, and I'm trying to create a loop. Here is my data (from a MongoDB database):

```
[{  "name" : "John",
    "mail" : "john@domaintest.com" },
{   "name" : "Tom",
    "mail" : "tom@domaintest.com" },
{   "name" : "Pete",
    "mail" : "pete@domaintest.com" }]
```

I would get a result similar to this:

```
<ul>
    <li>John : john@domaintest.com</li>
    <li>Tom : tom@domaintest.com</li>
    <li>Pete : pete@domaintest.com</li>
</ul>
```

So I tried this (and it works):

```
<ul>
    {#.}<li>{name} : {mail}</li>{~n}{/.}
<ul>
```

I wonder if defining a context with `{#.}{/.}` is the best way to achieve this (without that it does not work), it seems to me not clean compared to the doc, what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the way to do it. 
otherwise declare your context like:

```
{names: [
    {name : 'John', mail: 'john@domaintest.com'},
    ...
```

and then update your template to:

```
<ul>
    {#names}<li>{name} : {mail}</li>{~n}{/names}
<ul>
```